# Angular + Docker: trouble with docker-compose

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I prepare Dockerfile for my angular application, which looks like that:

```
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine AS builder
COPY . ./ToDoApp
WORKDIR /ToDoApp
RUN npm i
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
COPY --from=builder /ToDoApp/dist/ToDoApp/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I use commands:

```
docker build --rm -t todoapp:latest .
docker run --rm -d -p 90:80/tcp todoapp:latest
```

and site was avaiable on available:90.

No I trying prepare docker-compose.yml which I use to run my website and other services. Everything is works except my website. I have no idea why it didn't work. I still get a message "todoapp exited with code 0".

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  todoapp:
    container_name: todoapp
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./ToDoApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It seems your Dockerfile doesn't run an actual webserver, `ng build` only builds angular but doesn't actually serve it. Exited with 0 means that there was no error, it just ran successfully because it finished building. If you also have nginx service in your docker-compose you need to make sure to mount its html folder together with your own container.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Actually I noticed that you have nginx image in your Dockerfile. And you do copy the files to the right place apparently. But I am not sure now does nginx actually start when you run this container? You can try the solution Talha Junaid suggested.

Comment: I tired but not helped :(

Comment: How do you run your docker-compose?

Comment: docker-compose up

Comment: what if you really add `CMD ["nginx", "-c", "/data/conf/nginx.conf"]` at the end of your dockerfile? third parameter is path to your nginx config.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep your container running in detached mode, you need to run something in the foreground. An easy way to do this is to tail the `/dev/null` device as the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command of your Docker image.

Add the following as the last step in your docker file

```
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/07/how-to-keep-docker-containers-running/